# Is it best practice to not have App.js extend React.Component?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

If I create a new project with `create-react-app`, I get an `App.js` module where the default export, `App`, is just a function, and therefore doesn't have `state`, which is annoying. Does this suggest that I should have a (root) component under `App` if I want root level state, or should I just make my `App` extend `React.Component`? I don't want to go against convention, and it seems like there's a reason, so thought I would ask.

Comment: can have `state` with `hooks`

Comment: @BBaysinger depends on requirement if you need state and lifecycle method then you use class based component otherwise stateless, now in react 16 you can use state and lifecycle both in hooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is best practice to [use Functional component over Class-Component](https://medium.com/@Zwenza/functional-vs-class-components-in-react-231e3fbd7108). **If that is possible**.

Because `create-react-app` doesn't know you need state it creates simplest solution for you which you may change. There is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the link. Great answer!